# How to return the max value of two numeric columns concatenated by a decimal point in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has big numbers and small numbers. The big number represents the numbers before the decimal point. The small number represents the numbers after the decimal point. I am trying to make a query that will return the maximum number that can be created this way. A big number can only be paired with a small number if there is a row with them together.

| ID | big_number | small_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 7 |
| 6 | 2 | 7001 |
| 7 | 2 | 7003 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | 3 |

With the numbers above, I want the query to return 4.3.

Here is what I was able to come up with so far:

```
with temptable (max_big_number) as 
(
    select max(big_number) as max_big_number 
    from numbers
)
select max(small_number), max(big_number) 
from numbers, temptable 
where big_number = temptable.max_big_number;
```

This query returns 4 for the `max(big_number)` and 1 for the `max(small_number)`, but I can't figure out how to combine them into 4.3.

Comment: which database you are using, in case of sql_server
CONCAT(max(small_number), max(big_number)) should do it

Comment: What if you have multiple records with the same 'big_number' but different 'small_number'? Do you want the min or max 'small_number' there?

Comment: I'd just use math. Convert your small number to precision with ex. for big number 300 and small number 247. 300 + cast(247 as float)/cast(power(10, ceiling(log10(247))) as float) . Then the max of that.

Comment: What is the datatype of `small_number`? Why is there a trailing zero for `30`, `40`,`50` but `10` is just stored as `1`?

Comment: Why is the max not 4.5?

Comment: Is the small number 10 greater or less than the small number 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data and algorithm seem to imply you want to take the descending values of both the big_number and small_number together since you want a single decimal number.  You can calculate just the `max(big_number)` then figure out the small_number in a subsequent step (using the index to join back for example), but an easier and probably more efficient way is to take the top 1 row of those two columns in descending order.  Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(big_number, '.', small_number) AS [mynumber]
  FROM temptable
ORDER BY big_number DESC, small_number DESC
```

Where `CONCAT()` just concatenates the column values into a single string.